# Generics with inheritance error

Tags: swift, generics, covariance

I have an 2 objects inheriting from the same further.
And a Generic object Of the furthers type.
I want to save a list of generic object but i get an error.

> //Error: Cannot convert value of Type Node to expected argument type Node

Code:

```
class Pet {

}

class Cat: Pet {

}

class Dog: Pet {

}


public class Node<T> {
public var value: T

    public init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

var list = [Node<Pet>]()

//Error: Cannot convert value of Type Node<Dog> to expected argument type Node<Pet>
list.append(Node<Dog>(value: Dog()))
```

Why is this happening? any suggestions?

---

EDIT:

If Dog is of Kind Pet why cant i create a list of Node
And add to it a Node?

Comment: you can try this: `list.append(Node(value: Dog()))` and `list.append(Node(value: Cat()))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift is strict about types. You can't append `Node<Dog>` when `Node<Pet>` is expected.

---

You can cast optionally to necessary type by yourself `Dog() as Pet`:

```
list.append(Node(value: Dog()))
// or
list.append(Node<Pet>(value: Dog()))
// or
list.append(Node<Pet>(value: Dog() as Pet))
```

Later if you need to access the object and get the correct type, you have to downcast:

```
if let myDog = list[0].value as? Dog {
  print("woff woff")
}
```

See the [working demo](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58186f26a4f00b2ff0c5821e).

Read more details about [type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

Answer (score 1):

if you have a foundation like this:

```
class Pet { }
class Cat: Pet { }
class Dog: Pet { }
class Tiger: Cat { }

public class Node<T> {
    public var value: T   
    public init(value: T) { self.value = value }
}
```

---

then you could do something like that:

```
var list = [Node<Pet>]()
list.append(Node(value: Dog()))
list.append(Node(value: Cat()))
list.append(Node(value: Tiger()))
```